# Django object is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have the following code for serializing the queryset:

```
def get_shop_categories(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parent_id = int(request.POST.get('parent_id'))

        categories = (ShopCategory.objects.filter(enabled=True, parent=parent_id).values('id', 'title'))
        json_posts = json.dumps(categories)

        return HttpResponse(
            json_posts,
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"success": False}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

What I want it returns is this:

```
[{'id': 2, 'title': 'Tennis'}, {'id': 4, 'title': 'Basket'}]
```

Instead I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError at /ajax/get_shop_categories
[{'id': 2, 'title': 'Tennis'}, {'id': 4, 'title': 'Basket'}] is not JSON serializable
```

I also used serialize in this way:

```
categories = ShopCategory.objects.filter(enabled=True, parent=parent_id)                       
#json_posts = json.dumps(categories)
#objectQuerySet = ConventionCard.objects.filter(ownerUser = user)
json_posts = serializers.serialize('json', list(categories), fields=('id', 'title'))
```

but what I get I don't like:

```
 [{"fields":{"title":"Tennis"},"pk":2,"model":"appname.shopcategory"},{"fields":{"title":"Basket"},"pk":4,"model":"appname.shopcategory"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
categories = ShopCategory.objects.filter(enabled=True, parent=parent_id).values('id', 'title')
json_posts = mark_safe(json.dumps(list(categories), ensure_ascii=False))
```